# What happens when we change the order of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I was doing my homework and thought of a question none of my teachers were able to answer.

Suppose an integral:

$$  \int_{0}^{3} \int_{y-6}^{-y} x-y \,dx\,dy$$

The result is 36.

However, upon changing the order of integration, I still receive a result (though the result is a function).

My question is: What does this result represent? I know it's an incorrect way when calculating an integral with function bounds, but the result exists, I just want to know what it means.

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate the integral you get when you change the order of integration. If you are not getting a numerical answer, you are not getting the bounds of your integrals correct. **HINT**: You will need the sum of *two* iterated integrals.

Comment: P.S. Your result of $36$ is incorrect. It should be $-36$.

Comment: @TedShifrin If I understand then they did not mean the standard procedure of changing the order of integration, but literally $\int_{y-6}^{-y}\int_0^3$ which would give a function dependent on $y$. To the OP: this is just completely changing the meaning of the problem. The original integral on some shape (draw it) while the one with the integrals reversed is integrating $x-y$ on a rectangle which is sliding as you change $y$, so it depends on $y$. This is not a meaningful thing to do. There's a procedure called changing order of integration which does make sense and will also result in 36.